# Count function in SQL showing inaccurate numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have this query which selects the date and shows all the attribute values associated with those dates.

When I download the data I get from the 1st query shown below, the number of values associated with a single date - take 07/12/2022 for example - is 12. But when I count the attribute_value (as shown in the second query), I see a count of 139 instead of 12 associated with the attribute_value.

Does anyone happen to know what I'm doing wrong?

```
SELECT
  DATE(b.block_timestamp) AS timestamp,
  attribute_value
FROM `immaculate-355716.stride_1.event_attributes` ea
INNER JOIN `immaculate-355716.stride_1.blocks` b
ON CAST(ea.block_height AS STRING) = b.block_height
WHERE ea.attribute_key = 'packet_src_port'
AND ea.attribute_value LIKE 'icacontroller%'
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1 DESC`

SELECT
  DATE(b.block_timestamp) AS timestamp,
  COUNT(attribute_value) AS count
FROM `immaculate-355716.stride_1.event_attributes` ea
INNER JOIN `immaculate-355716.stride_1.blocks` b
ON CAST(ea.block_height AS STRING) = b.block_height
WHERE ea.attribute_key = 'packet_src_port'
AND ea.attribute_value LIKE 'icacontroller%'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: The first thing I would try out is adding a DISTINCT: COUNT(DISTINCT attribute_value) AS count. Does this make a difference? Would be great to see some sample data here.

Comment: The first query is group by `timestamp` and `attribute_value`; the second query, `timestamp` alone, so that you may have repeated values in `attribute_value` column. Remove '2' from the group by of the first query to verify.

Comment: I wouldn't truest a group by with no aggregation..